# How to bind WebAPI controller action parameter either by URL part or querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have an API method defined as such:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpGet("{itemType}/{itemId}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string itemType, string itemId)
    {
        return Ok($"{itemType}/{itemId}");
    }
}
```

Calling this works:

```
/api/items/person/0123
```

Calling the action by *querystring* results in `UnprocessableEntity`

```
/api/items?itemType=person&itemId=0123
```

How can I define my action method so that it accepts both types of input?

Comment: You can define another one action with different name that accepts parameters from query

Comment: @Batangaming that does work indeed, thanks. However, I'd prefer a single-action solution, if possible. I can use this as a temporary solution though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, so that the first route will allow you to use querystring and the second one will allow values to be bound to the variables through attribute routing.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    [HttpGet("{itemType}/{itemId}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string itemType, string itemId)
    {
        return Ok($"{itemType}/{itemId}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, indeed, but unfortunately with the same failing result.